# How to loop through list in Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am having a list in the name 'bestforproglist'. Also I had a `for` loop like this

```
{% for act in activities %}
    <div style="float:left;">{{ act.spotcategoryactivity }}</div>

    <div class="progit">
            <div class="prog_c" >
                <div id="prog_p" style="width:20%;"></div>
            </div>
            <span id="p_caps">{{ ____________ }}%</span><br/>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

in the above code, in the space of **underline**, how should i have have first item in the list when the loop is in first iteration, the second item in the list when the loop is in second iteration and so on...

I tried

```
<span id="p_caps">{{ mylist[ {{forloop.counter}} ] }}</span><br/>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: you cant use  list['key'] in templates, it can be accessed as list.key instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is `mylist`? If you want to iterate over multiple lists, perhaps you should `zip` them and pass them into the template? Then you can use something like

```
 {% for x,y in zipped_list %}
```

and use both the items rather than the indexing thing you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important to have `activities` and `bestforproglist` synchronized like this then it's best to `zip()` them in the view and then iterate over both of them together.

```
{% for act, prog in zippedlist %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In template , code like this
"""  mylist[ {{forloop.counter}} ] """  won`t work.

use "." instead.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables

this will make you  clear about how to output things in template